# How to handle REST API webservice captcha verification request?

Tags: java, jax-rs, captcha, zillow

I am implementing a client to Zillow GetDeepSearchResults Api (https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetDeepSearchResults.htm) using jax-rs. However I get a captcha verification request as response

I am able to get the captcha properly validated by the end user localhost:8080/Myapp/. But after the validation, I am redirected to the server root (localhost:8080)?

I got the captcha response as a string.

```
public String getLocation(String address) {
           return client
              .target(REST_URI)
              .path(String.valueOf(address))
              .request(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
              .get(String.class);
        }
```

I then displayed the captcha

```
<h:outputText value="#{mainBean.details}" escape="false"></h:outputText>
```

But after the validation, I am redirected to the server root (localhost:8080)?

How do I catch the response from the API after the validation. I need to get the XML that is returned.